# How can I detect a jQuery ajax error response?

Tags: jquery, api, jsonp, http-status-codes

I am able to detect a successful response but not able to detect an error. My code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',      
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(a, b) { 
                if(b=="Processing post"){
                    $("#post_response").html('Your comment will be added soon...'); 
                }
                else if(b=="In moderation"){
                    $("#post_response").html('Your comment has been placed in moderation...');  
                }
            })
        },
        error: function(xhr, testStatus, error) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

These are the responses I am receiving. I can detect the first 2 response but I cannot even alert "error" for the last one.

```
jQuery191004289518775843171_1361906819321({"Message":"Processing post","Code":202})

jQuery191006158838421090984_1361907415719({"Message":"In moderation","Code":202})

jQuery191006158838421090984_1361907415719({"Message":"Not logged in","Code":403})
```

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you can't catch request errors with JSONP. If the server is returning a text status of 403 in addition to the jsonp, jQuery won't be able to handle it.

Comment: Have you asserted that `success` isn't being called in the third case? Try adding a `console.log` or `alert`.

Comment: I tried adding else if(b=="Not logged in"){$("#post_response").html('You are not logged in'); } to success but it was not picked up.

Comment: How can I modify my code to pickup "Not logged in"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error callback is only used for server error responses (i.e. HTTP Status Code 4xx/5xx Errors).  Since all three of your responses are valid (i.e. they return a HTTP Status Code of 200), they trigger the success callback.

Comment: As an addition, it would be helpfull to note what triggers the error-response. Most notably the http headers 500 and 404. For more information, check the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks... I just edited my answer to include that detail.  However, I couldn't find an exact list of failure status codes. I always thought it was all 4xx and 5xx codes.

Comment: Just checked the code of jquery and you are right, the following if statements check if it was a success: status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304 (Which means that everything else results in an error)

Comment: Firebug is showing the status as 202 Accepted (for "Processing post" and "In moderation"), 403 Forbidden (for "Not logged in")